# Configuration file error, the fopen instruction can't find the file or directory

Tags: c, file, configuration, config

I'm trying to read a configuration file with

```
FILE * config = fopen("value.conf", "r");
```

But when I compile and run it, I get this error

```
PID=   54: Error 2 (No such file or directory)
```

The problem is… there is a file `value.conf` in the directory. How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you mean execute instead of compile.

Comment: Is `value.conf` in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: That error message can't be created by the compiler, but rather when you *run* your program. It means that the file `value.conf` can't be found in the current working directory of the process (which doesn't have to be the same directory as the executable file). How do you run your program?

Comment: Sorry, I meant compile.

Comment: The problem is that the conf file is in the same directory of my program. I run it by command line